# Vector operations in pandas with datatime object not working

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I am trying to do the following operation in pandas

```
new_data["age_in_days"] = ( datetime(new_data["year"],6,30)-new_data["date"] ).days
```

which should calculate on the column "age_in_days" the age of the object. But indeed, I get an error message: "TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>".
"date" is a DateTime object. "year" is an int.

Running this for just one object (e.g the one with index=2), on the other side, works perfectly as expected:

```
new_data["age_in_days"][2] = ( datetime(new_data["year"][2],6,30)-new_data["date"][2] ).days
```

What should I do to make it work? Is it because of unhandled NaNs? I would expect the "age_in_days" then to be also just NaN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to use datetime with a whole df column instead of an int and then use this output which will be an int to redefine your df column.
so what you need to do here is apply your desired behavior to each line.

```
new_data["age_in_days"] =new_data.apply(lambda x :(datetime(x["year"],6,30)-x["date"]).days, axis=1)
```

this should work

Comment: yes, indeed that works. But I dont understand why. 
When doing 

new_data["test"] =new_data["int1"] - new_data["int2"]

I can also manipulate each row. What is different here and why do I need to use .apply here?

Comment: in your exemple here you are substracting two clomuns so it outputs a columns, which is the result you want. but in the original question, you wanted to use datetime, which takes an int in input, not a column, that's why. Furthurmore, your whole line outputs an int, not a column. Is it clearer now ?